# Map tiles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tiles, maptiler

I want to create georeferenced map tiles from raster (jpg map of small area) and display in Leaflet. MapTiler seems to be a prefect solution for my problem, but free version doesn't allow set zoom range, aslo has a watermark. 
Is there any free/opensource solution with same funcionality? Im woking on non-profit project, so dont have any budget.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641838/4768502 for a pointer to `gdal2tiles`.

You can also use other software such as GeoServer, MapServer or MapProxy to serve tiles based on an image or some vector data.